# UML reduce number extend and implement connections

Tags: uml, extend, implements, visual-paradigm

I have a project in which a lot of classes extends and/or implements a class and/or an interface. It already is splitted in logical components, but yet sometimes all of those connections make the diagrams messy.

Is there a way to reduce this number of connections?
Something like telling a whole subpackage extends/implements a class/interface?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not make a package implement an interface. However, you can leave out the interface from a diagram or suppress the connectors and just place it as a note aside. For example:

[image]

could be shown as

[image]

Comment: What about extensions? There's no way to do that without breaking a design software capability to generate code?

Comment: Suppressing connectors in a diagram is a question of presentation, not of the model which still has the connectors.